# Can I use Generics to get the property of a passed struct?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use Generics to pass in a struct to a function and then have that function access its properties. I want to utilize Generics more because they are supposed to be "safe and efficient". Here's what my code looks like.

Class

```
class foo { 
    struct A { 
       int a;
       int b
    }

    struct B {
       int a;
       int b;
    } 
}
```

Generic Function

```
void bar<T> (T input) {
    var a = input.a;       //this is where its says it know nothing about a
}
```

Function Call

```
bar<foo.A> (Aobj);
```

Can Generics be used like this?(That is to access the object's data members...)
Or is all I can do is create an over-loaded method? The only parts of the objects that I am trying to access from the function are common to both types, so that's also why I thought I could use Generics.

Comment: you would have to use refection to get properties

Comment: Why do you want to use generics here?

Comment: You can use a common `interface`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using generics does not imply that you can use duck typing. C# is a statically typed language, so you need to do something like the following:

First, define an interface that defines the common interface of `A` and `B`:

```
interface IHasAB
{
    int A { get; }
    int B { get; }
}
```

Then, have your `struct`s implement this interface:

```
struct A : IHasAB
{
    public A(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public int A { get; }  // Note: `A` and `B` are now properties, not fields
    public int B { get; }  // like before; interfaces do not allow you to declare fields.

    // Note also: mutable structs are a bad idea! That's why we implement
    // `A` and `B` as read-only properties.
}

struct B : IHasAB { … }  // same as for `A`
```

Now you can implement your method `bar` with an additional generic type parameter constraint `where T : IHasAB`:

```
void bar<T> (T input) where T : IHasAB
{
    var a = input.A;
}
```

The constraint on `T` lets the compiler know what it can expect `T` to be. It now knows that `T` is a type that implements `IHasAB`, and therefore has two properties `A` and `B` (since that is what the interface consists of). That's why you can now access `.A` on `input`.

Note that you don't necessarily need to make `bar` generic:

```
void bar(IHasAB input)
{
    var a = input.A;
}
```

In this latter case, note that `input` is now a reference-typed parameter. If you passed one of your `A` or `B` structs to that method, it would have to be boxed (i.e. turned from a value type into a reference type). There's some overhead involved in that.

I won't go further into the dangers of mutable structs and the boxing that can easily happen in situations where structs implement interfaces, since that's quite a different matter altogether; I would recommend that you spend a little time researching these topics. ;-)

Comment: Note that `A` and `B` are structs now, not properties.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Are you referring to the types `A` and `B`, or to the properties `A` and `B`? In the former case, they were `struct`s before, and they still are. (Yes btw., I am probably missing a hint about boxing.) In the latter case, you probably meant that they're now properties, not fields.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You were just showing the struct, not the class.

Comment: If desired, one could further constraint the generic `bar` method to `where T : struct, IHasAB`.

Comment: Wow a lot of good information here, would you also use the interface to access methods if you were feeding it a class instead of a function?

Comment: @chewbapoclypse: It really depends where some functionality / behaviour logically belongs. If you have code like `if (obj is A) { DoThisWith(obj); } else if (obj is B) { DoThatWith(obj); }`, then you're probably be better off declaring a `DoSomething` method in the interface, have your types implement the respective behaviour themselves, then replace the above `if` with simple delegation of the form `obj.DoSomething()`.

Comment: @EliArbel: In this particular case, there won't be any boxing, but once you start using interfaces, sooner or later you will have a method with a parameter of type `IHasAB`, and when you pass an `A` or `B` struct to such a method, you will cause boxing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `T` to specific type before accessing member like

```
void bar<T> (T input) 
{
    var obj = T as foo;
    if (obj != null)
       var a = obj.A;      
}
```

Comment: Why not narrow down `T` using `where T : foo`? But hey, what is the use of the generic then?

Comment: And besides that, there is no property or field `a` in `foo`. Your code doesn't work either.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, exactly and see that commented by you but it's per what OP posted as question.

Comment: Can you specify it to more than one?  Like `where T : foo and foo1`?

Comment: @chewbapoclypse, what's `foo1`? another class? then NO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to the compiler what kind of type you're expecting T to be. Your method `bar<T>` knows absolutely nothing about `T`, except for that it *must* be a type that is *at least* of type `object` or a subclass of `object`. This means that you can use all the methods that are defined in `object` on `T`.

However, if you want to be able to use `a`, you need to tell `bar<T>` that  `T` is going to be of a type that implements property `a`. That's where interfaces come into play. This means you need to create a superclass or better yet an interface that demands the implementation of `a`, so you can tell `bar<T>` that `T` is at least of type `<your interface>`. See the below code:

```
interface ImanInterfaceWithA {
     int a {get; set;}
}

class foo { 
    struct A : ImanInterfaceWithA { 
       public int a {get; set;}
       public int b {get; set;}
    }

    struct B : ImanInterfaceWithA {
       public int a {get; set;}
       public int b {get; set;}
    } 


    void bar<T> (T input) where T : IamanInterfaceWithA
    {
        var a = input.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, except interfaces are not allowed to have fields (variables), only properties. See answer by `stakx`.

Comment: You're absolutely right of course. Ill clean up my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `dynamic`.

```
void bar<T> (T input) {
    dynamic a = input.a;       //this is where its says it know nothing about a
}
```

Comment: No, that has nothing  to do with the use of generics.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I seriously doubt that there would be only one line of code as in example.

Comment: Your code not compile, input is of type `T` that doesn't have an `a` field or property.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria is right. You need either `void bar(dynamic input)`, or you need to box/cast to `dynamic` as in `var a = ((dynamic)input).a;`.

Comment: It should actually be `dynamic a = ((dynamic)input).a;`

Comment: Still, given the fact that you can assign (hopefully) the value in `input.a`, this has nothing to with generic types. What is the point of `T` in this example, if you're just going to cast it to a dynamic type.